# How do I replace white spaces to nbsp?

Tags: java, string, replace

How do I convert any white spaces to nbsp? This doesn't seem to work for me:

```
String temp = "This is practice";
temp = temp.replaceAll(" ", "nbsp");
```

It is literally adding the string nbsp in, how do I make it so it actually counts as a no break space?

Answer (score 6):

To replace literally all "whitespace" (spaces, tabs, etc), do this:

```
temp = temp.replaceAll("\\s", "&nbsp;");
```

`\s` is the regex for "whitespace".

Answer (score 3):

Unicode 'no-break space' character has code `0xA0`, so, instead of an HTML entity, you could use it directly: `"\u00A0"`.

Answer (score 2):

The correct string to use is `"&nbsp;"`

so your code should be

```
temp = temp.replace(" ", "&nbsp;");
```

Comment: cheers @9000 for your edit

Comment: @AlexPap I can not see the code that you are referring to in the above question, or anywhere else on this page.